# Differential Geometry, plane rotating around coordiante line

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, parametric, plane-curves

I am self studying Differntial Geometry with Do Carmo and I am attempting problem 9 of section 2-4.

Specifically I am confused about the rotation statement.

After not understanding that part I had to peek at the solution in [Slader](https://www.slader.com/textbook/9780132125895-differential-geometry-of-curves-and-surfaces/89/exercises/9/):

But I am still confused.

If we define $u=u_0$ then the coordinate remains fixed. This in turn means that that normal, defined as:

$<\sin(u_0)a, -\cos(u_0)a, v>$ is not rotating.

For it to rotate I would need to fix $v$ and let $u$ be the one that varies, i.e. $<\sin(u)a, -\cos(u)a, v_0>$.

I may be misreading the question too. The question, for those that do not have access to the book is:

> Given the surface $X(u,v)=<v\cos(u), v\sin(u), au>, a\neq 0$ Compute it's normal $N(u,v)$ and show that along the coordinate line $u=u_0$ the tangent plane of $x$ rotates about this line in such a way that the tangent of its angle with the $z$axis is proportional to its distance $v=\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ of the point $X(u_0, v)$ to the $z$ axis.

What am I misreading about the question?

Comment: Yes, the normal is rotating (not trigonometrically) about the fixed ruling of the helicoid. At $v=0$ the normal is horizontal (tangent plane vertical), and as $v\to\infty$ the normal approaches the vertical (tangent plane approaches horizontal).

Comment: What do you mean it is not rotating trigonometically?

Comment: I mean the obvious thing. The formula for the unit normal is not given by trigonometric functions of $v$. Nevertheless, the vector is *turning* about the ruling as $v$ varies.